# reactjs setState doesn't change properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small react app. When selected dep/arr station changes it refetches the schedule data from the BART API.

For some reason with the old code (see below) it didn't work properly. I did `setState` first then tried to use the new value of the `depStation`, but it showed the previous value. So for instance let's say I reload the page the initial depState value is `SFIA`. If I change the value to `FRMT` then the `console.log(selected)` shows `FRMT` but the `console.log(this.state.depStation)` still shows `SFIA`. If I change it again to `HAYW` the `console.log(selected)` shows `HAYW` but the `console.log(this.state.depStation)` shows `FRMT`. To make the app work I simply just used the `selected` instead of the `this.state.depStation`, but I guess this is not the best approach.

So I don't really understand why `this.state.depStation` shows the prev data after calling `this.setState({depStation: selected})`. Could sby explain me why this is happening?

Old version which was not working:

```
reRunFetching(selected, type) {
  if (type === "depart") {
    this.setState({depStation: selected});
    console.log(selected); //Showing properly what I select
    console.log(this.state.depStation); //For some reason the previously selected
  }
  else if (type === "arrive") {
    this.setState({arrStation: selected});
  }
  this.fetchingAPI(this.state.depStation, this.state.arrStation)
}
```

New version. This is working fine, but I guess it's not the best solution:

```
reRunFetching(selected, type) {
  if (type === "depart") {
    this.fetchingAPI(selected, this.state.arrStation)
    this.setState({depStation: selected});
    console.log(selected, this.state.arrStation);
  }
  else if (type === "arrive") {
    this.fetchingAPI(this.state.depStation, selected)
    this.setState({arrStation: selected});
    console.log(this.state.depStation, selected);
  }
}
```

rest of index.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      schedules: [],
      depStation: DEP_STATION,
      arrStation: ARR_STATION
    };

    this.fetchingAPI(this.state.depStation, this.state.arrStation)
  }

  fetchingAPI(departureStation, arrivalStation) {
    fetch("http://api.bart.gov/api/sched.aspx?cmd=depart&orig=" + departureStation + "&dest=" + arrivalStation + "&date=now&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V&b=0&a=4&l=0")
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();})
    .then((responseXML) => {
      let tripsArray = this.parsingXML(responseXML);
      this.setState({schedules: tripsArray});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 search-bar">
            <SelectDepart onSelectedChange={selected => this.reRunFetching(selected, "depart")}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-5 search-bar">
            <SelectArrive onSelectedChange={selected => this.reRunFetching(selected, "arrive")}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <TimeTable schedules={this.state.schedules} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState() is an asynchronous non-blocking method which doesn't immediately set the new state, as you expect it to. As the official docs says:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>   There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

If you need you can pass a callback a a second argument to setState() and it will be fired on state change:

```
this.setState({depStation: selected}, function() {
// some code
});
```

Comment: Ilya, what do you think of my current working version? Is that worse/better compared to what you are suggesting?

Comment: If the order of operations  - setState() and fetchingAPI() - is not important, (they're independent), then your workaround fits. If there are or may rise some side effect e.g. race conditions, then it's better to call fetchingAPI() in a callback passed to setState() to ensure the order of execution.

Answer (score 0):

setState() is an asynchronous method which queue your state. so in order to access state value immidiately after setState you need to call a callback function as second argument to setState method, which will first set your state and after that will re render your view with updated state. below example will help you.

```
this.setState({
   depStation: selected
}, () => {
  // here you will get your depStation state value
  console.log(this.state.depStation,"depStation value")
});
```